How to link to an issue on GitLab, including the issue status?
I am trying to find a way to link to a GitLab issue so that the link shows an icon/badge/shield with the status of the issue.  I.e., something like this (using shields.io):
<img
src="https://img.shields.io/gitlab/issues/status/forbes-group/cookiecutters/1">


Unfortunately, it seems that only summary badges are currently supported, like this:
<img
src="https://img.shields.io/gitlab/issues/all/forbes-group/cookiecutters">


The information is obtainable with the GitLab API:
$ curl -v 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/forbes-group%2fcookiecutters/issues?iids=1'
...
"state":"active"
...

but I can't seem to find any tools that use this yet.  Is there a simple way to do this without writing a custom rule or doing external processing to generate the badge?  (Is there something similar for GitHub?)
